# gulp - how can I exclude a file which is referenced in other added files?

Tags: typescript, gulp

I am trying to exclude this app/custom.ts file from gulp concatenated file. However I noticed that since custom.ts file is referenced in one of other files, custom.ts file is not excluded even though I try to exclude it.

Is it the normal behaviour ? Or am I doing something wrong here ?

How can I exclude this file or use it in a separate  bundle ?

```
gulp.task('app-bundle', function () {
  var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
      typescript: require('typescript'),
      outFile: 'app.js'
  });

  var tsResult = gulp.src([
      '!app/custom.ts',
      'app/**/*.ts'
  ]).pipe(ts(tsProject));

  return tsResult.js.pipe(addsrc.append('config-prod.js'))
                    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gulp-ignore https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ignore to ignore a particular file from the pipeline. As per the example provided in the sample add

```
.pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(condition))
```

before

```
.pipe(addsrc.append('config-prod.js'))
```

of your code.